# How Can Format Text Inside TextBoxes In WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, format

as you know in web applications there are some third party libraries that we can use for convert a text box to an editor like below :
[tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/)
but what about win forms?
how can i format text inside Text Boxes in win forms?
i mean i want to convert regular text boxes in a form to an editor by setting a property(is it possible or not?).
how can i do that?

Comment: You can create your own editor :)

Comment: use richtextbox control on windows forms [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tdc88y7.aspx)

Comment: i checked richtextbox, but there is no buttons inside it for changing color-bold-italic-etc

Comment: you have to write it your self...just spend some time on  this. richtextbox has all function and on each button you have to call those function...

Comment: is there any third party control instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public void CreateMyRichTextBox()
  {
      RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
      richTextBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


      richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\\MyDocument.rtf");
      richTextBox1.Find("Text", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);

      richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
      richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

      richTextBox1.SaveFile("C:\\MyDocument.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

      this.Controls.Add(richTextBox1);
  }
```